# Are there any banks that don't require mobile phones for 2FA in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, online-banking

I have a current account with Santander, and when I make card payments over the internet they send me a one-time-passcode (OTP) in a text message, as a form of two-factor authentication (2FA). My phone is not currently working, so I can't receive those messages, and can't use my card.

My phone will work again soon, but I never want to have this problem again. I am not opposed to 2FA, but only two mechanisms seem acceptable as alternatives:

- Email passcodes
- Time based one time passcodes, where I can generate the codes myself using an app/program

I much prefer the second option. Are there any banks that support this method of 2FA?

Comment: Product / service recommendations are off-topic. But to be nice, I will give you https://2fa.directory/gb/#banking which I got to approximately 1 minute after googling `uk bank  that allows yubikey for 2fa`

Comment: @AakashM Thanks, that's a really useful site regardless! You didn't actually find one that supports Yubikey, did you? Under "hardware", I can only find the card machines user71659 mentions in their answer.

Comment: UK banks tend to have a strong 'Not Invented Here' syndrome in terms of their technology operations, so they much prefer to build their own card readers, or re-badge a white-label offering, rather than integrate with an existing product

Answer (score 0):

The solution banks have come up with is the Chip Authentication Program, or CAP. This uses a handheld reader and the existing EMV chip and pin in your card to generate a one-time password. This reuses the existing security work done for EMV chips.

The [Wikipedia article for CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_Authentication_Program) lists a number of UK banks that support it.

Comment: This definitely satisfies most of my requirements (the ideal would actually be a software solution I control, but a hardware solution is better than software I don't control). It's a shame they're so bulky!

Comment: Even better: There is a software project that appears to emulate the functionality of the device (https://github.com/doegox/EMV-CAP). Unclear how complete it is.